# How to make this floating table fixed in corrent way?

Tags: tables, positioning

I have 3 tables: 1,2,3 and text that I need to have near table 3 (before & after). LaTeX's  allocated table 1 and 2 on page 4 and table 3 on page 5, but I need this table (3) to be allocated with the text on page 3. And when I use

```
\usepackage{float}
\begin{table}[H]
...`
```

it is stuck on page 3, but now the table 3 shows up earlier than table 1 and 2, which is kind of not what I want.
I don't know if I explained this corrently, hope you know what I mean.

Comment: `H` means do not float. so it does what you ask, even if other tables float past it. Just not using `H` is usually the best advice.

Comment: Welcome, the correct way to not let a table float is not using a `table` environment. On the other hand, `[H]` should work as well. You can also put multiple tables and captions into *one* `table` environment.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example? (`\documentclass`, `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` with the setup you are using so that we can exactly reproduce you problem?
And a simple question: Have you given LaTex multiple runs (at least two) to try get the numbers right?

Comment: Really you should provide a testable example, but what options have you used on the other tables, why are they floating to the end?

Comment: Maybe you have to much restrictions for the floats. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149413/placing-many-floating-tables or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lax. Maybe you should simply put all three `tabulars` inside one `table`.

Comment: @Timm multiple runs won't change the numbering.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you guys. I did simplest thing possible - \clearpage before text :p and it worked!